# Wrong Years in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-char

I have been trying to work this problem out for hours. My numbers are about a year off. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the question and expected results:
[image]
Create a list of student names from area code 203 along with the number of years
since they registered (show 2 decimal places on all values).
Sort the list on the number of years from highest to lowest.

Here is my code and results:

```
SELECT First_Name,
       Last_Name,
       TO_CHAR((ROUND(SYSDATE - registration_date) / 365), '9.99') AS YEARS
FROM Student
WHERE Phone LIKE '203-%%%-%%%%' 
ORDER BY  Years DESC  ;
```

[image]

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: FYI: `%` matches zero or more characters, `_` matches exactly one character.

Comment: gloomy.penguin can you help?

Comment: Looks like it works fine to me. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33f2f/5). Share and enjoy.

Comment: Is the data you're using, including the registration dates, fixed in the assignment? If so, maybe the example output was just created a bit more than a year ago? Since the query is based on the current date, you'd expect the output to be different depending on when the query is executed, surely?

Comment: You should post questions as (plain) text. Posting a screenshot of your PDF reader is not helpful. The example output is also better posted as formatted plain text.

Comment: Another thing: Just dividing the number of days with 365 will give results that are slightly too small if there are leap years between registration date and sysdate. Might be too small an error to catch with two decimals, but with many leap years it just might be noticable. In that case you could consider something like `MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,REGISTRATION_DATE) / 12` or `MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE),REGISTRATION_DATE) / 12`.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is based on the current date, so with fixed values for the data you've been given, you would expect it to differ from the sample output in the question. That output is based on whenever the question was set and the query was run - whatever the date was that day. ([Apparently 2013-06-03](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66931/1), using an adjusted subset of the schema build [found here](http://arjudba.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/oracle-general-sql-exercise.html)).

So on that date, a registration date of, say, 2007-02-02 was 6.34 years ago, but it's now 1.33 years later, so the same query gets an answer of 7.67 today.

You're assuming the results have to match exactly what you've been given, when it's really only showing you the *format* it should be in. The exact number of years has to be expected to be different. So your query isn't wrong, you're misinterpreting the question slightly.

Also `ROUND` will give you slightly different results if the query is run in the morning or afternoon. It's more normal to use `TRUNC(sysdate)` to ignore the time portion. And as pointed put in comments, your wildcard usage is wrong, and you could just use `LIKE '203-%'`.